# Tabular with p type columns to fill page width

Tags: tables, columns, width

I wish to be able to have a table (using tabular) that fills the page horizontally with each column using a fraction of that space, for now assume that they are equally sized.

I wish to be able to use enumerations inside of the tabular, so I am using parabox's to achieve this.

Currently I have got:

```
\begin{tabular}{ | p{0.25\linewidth} |
                   p{0.25\linewidth} |
                   p{0.25\linewidth} |
                   p{0.25\linewidth} | } 
%content here after
```

except this uses all the space from the first margain to the end of the page. Which looks awful. I really want to avoid hard coding in any dimensions because I will want to play around with margins and orientation later.

If I could get it so that I can use a proportion of the text width for each column that would be great.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

each tabular column has on the left and right a separation of `\tabcolsep` which must be substract from the column width if you want it to be of the length `\linewidth`

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\hrulefill

\begin{tabular}{ | p{\dimexpr 0.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep} |
                   p{\dimexpr 0.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep} |
                   p{\dimexpr 0.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep} |
                   p{\dimexpr 0.25\linewidth-2\tabcolsep} | } \hline
foo & bar & baz & foobar \\\hline
\end{tabular}                

\end{document}
```

However, using `tabularx` makes more sense:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}

\hrulefill

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | X | X | X | X | } \hline
foo & bar & baz & foobar \\\hline
\end{tabularx}                

\end{document}
```

Comment: it isn't perfect (I think there is another separator unaccounted for somewhere) but it good enough for now.

Comment: no, then you are doing something wrong, e.g. a missing `\noindent` before the table if you have by default an indentation before paragraphs

Comment: Wouldn't your code generate a tabular environment that's `5*0.4pt=2pt` *wider* than `\linewidth` because of the five vertical bars (each of width `0.4pt`)?

Comment: no, only if you are using package `array` ...

Comment: The problem was me lacking `\noindent` thanks

Comment: If package `array` is loaded, then the width of a vertical line (`\arrayrulewidth`) also counts.

Answer (score 18):

You may be looking for something like the following, which requires loading the [tabularx](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/tools) package:

```
\noindent % needed if the tabularx environment isn't encased in a table environment
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{4}{X|}}
...
\end{tabularx}
```

In the title of your posting, you mention you want a solution using columns of type `p{<some width>}`. The `X` column provided by the `tabularx` package is essentially a `p` column; the `tabularx` package just saves you the tedium of having to calculate the column widths explicitly. :-)

---

**Addendum** This can be generalized to (a) tables that take up a width of less than `1\textwidth` -- just specify the intended width as the first argument of the `tabularx` environment, either as an absolute width statement (e.g., `10cm`) or as a relative width statement (e.g., `0.85\textwidth`) -- and (b) tables with unequal column widths. E.g., assume that the first and third columns, and the second and fourth columns in the first example should have equal widths, and that the second/fourth columns should be 50% wider than the first/third columns. This can be set up with the following (at first slightly bewildering) instruction

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X| >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X |
                              >{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X| >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X |}
```

Of course, this can be expressed slightly more succinctly as

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| *{2}{>{\hsize=0.8\hsize}X| >{\hsize=1.2\hsize}X |}}
```

The point to note is that the *sum* of the fractions of `\hsize` must equal the number of columns of type `X` (in this example, `4`).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that now, any ideas as to why my attempted didn't (to help my understanding of what is going on).

Comment: @111111 -- I believe your trial code is wider than `\linewidth` because you have (a) 5 vertical bars (each of default width `0.4pt`), (b) 3 intercolumn whitespaces (of default width `2\tabcolsep`), and (c) and 1 vertical whitespace each at the beginning and end of the table (each of default width `1\tabcolsep`). Finally, `\tabcolsep=5pt` by default. All this adds up to `2pt`+`40pt` = `42pt`, or almost `15mm`.

Comment: I have tried using tabularx with the columns being equal fraction of space I want them to take up (using \hsize=frac\hsize) as you have shown, but the enumerations are forcing a box to be larger for sum reason

Comment: @111111 -- please edit your question to post a MWE that generates the problem behavior you're encountering. Without having access to the precise code you're executing, it's well-nigh impossible to diagnose (let alone fix) the problem. Also, depending on the complexity of the tabularx setup, you may have to run latex more than once in order for the algorithm to "converge".

Comment: Sorry for being vague and thanks for your help. I went for accounting for the colsep in the size rather than tab'x because I need to get it done for now. But I will bear it in mind in the future.

Comment: @111111 -- OK. Just in case you also use the `array` package, be sure to modify @Herbert's code to take into account that each vertical bar has width `0.4pt`. Thus, if you have 5 vertical bars in the table and 4 columns, you should decrease the width of each column by `0.5pt`.

Comment: no, the first one by `2\arrayrulewidth` and the others by `\arrayrulewidth`

Comment: @Herbert -- First, isn't `\arrayrulewidth` equal to `0.4pt` be default in all of the main LaTeX document classes? Second, if the goal is to have columns of equal width, why would one apply different width adjustments for the first column and the other columns?

Comment: @Mico: the first column has two vertical lines, left _and_ right, all others only a right line. Compare using `\multicolumn` when redefining vertical rules.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to present an answer for beginners with Latex.

With the package `tabularx´ it's easy to set custom column widths.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial}

\usepackage[textwidth=16cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[htb]
%\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=.8\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.5\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.6\hsize}X|>{\hsize=1.5\hsize}X|>{\hsize=.6\hsize}X|}
\hline
\textbf{Framework} & \textbf{License} & \textbf{Functionality} & \textbf{Others} & \textbf{Support} \\
\hline
etc. & etc. & etc. & etc. & etc \\
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Our Framework}
\label{tab:framework}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Attention: hsize=.8\hsize is **not** the percentage of the whole textwidth.

It's a decleration for increase and decrease.

You have just to make sure that the sum of increase and decrease are the same.

-0.2 - 0.5 - 0.4 = - 1,1

0.6 + 0.5 = 1,1

That's it.