# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph for table

Tags: tables, line-breaking, warnings

I got a "bad box" warning said `!h'

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
Underfull \hbox (badness 2707) in paragraph
```

The source code is

```
\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Comparison of design requirements for adults and children}
\footnotesize
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.2\linewidth}|p{0.35\linewidth}|p{0.35\linewidth}|}
\hline \centering{Message} & \centering{Adults}  & \centering{Children} \tabularnewline 
\hline *M1-constraint-requirement-requirement-summary & ``The target user is an \textbf{adult}. Constraints - Ergonomics can be found in standard \textbf{XX1}.''& ``The target user is a \textbf{child}. Constraints - Ergonomics can be found in standard \textbf{XX2}.'' \tabularnewline 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

and it looks like this 
[image]

I don't know what's going wrong in my case.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! TeX is having problems in justification (that is in making lines of equal lengths) in those narrow columns. You probably want to use ragged right typesetting.

Comment: what egreg said, also note `\centering` does not take an argument: `\centering{Adults}` should be `\centering Adults` (the extra group is in this case harmless but doing northing)

Answer (score 7):

The lines of the first cell of the second line doesn't fill the `hbox`-es (3 bad boxes). Same at the third cell for one line (1 bad box). Using `\raggedright` can make these bad boxes go away without the real change of output. This is because the box is small but the words are long: you can't really use justification when you have 1 word per line. (If you have a few words per line, you can try `\sloppy`.)

The last bad box is caused by the fact that your tabular is larger than the actual `\hsize`. That's because it is wider than the sum of the column widths. Using the `showframe` package, you can clearly see that in the example below (`\raggedright` already added, 1 bad box remaining). You can fix this by resizing a column or changing the column separation (or check [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62710/tabular-with-p-type-columns-to-fill-page-width)).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
\caption{Comparison of design requirements for adults and children}
\footnotesize
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.35\textwidth}|p{0.35\textwidth}|}
\hline \centering{Message} & \centering{Adults}  & \centering{Children} \tabularnewline 
\hline \raggedright*M1-constraint-requirement-requirement-summary & \raggedright``The target user is an \textbf{adult}. Constraints - Ergonomics can be found in standard \textbf{XX1}.''& \raggedright``The target user is a \textbf{child}. Constraints - Ergonomics can be found in standard \textbf{XX2}.'' \tabularnewline 
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```